# Eval not working on multi-line string

Tags: python, eval

I am having issues with executing a multi-line string with the python eval function/

```
code = ''' 

def main():
  print "this is a test"

main()

'''

eval(code)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    eval(code)
  File "<string>", line 3
    def main():
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Using `eval` is usually not recommended. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698028/why-is-pythons-eval-rejecting-this-multiline-string-and-how-can-i-fix-it

Comment: IanAuld I am writing an automatic python grader which first must execute code received by a GET Request on a Flask Server

Comment: @JohnGalt: so you want to execute **arbitrary code** sent to you from a web client? That's a security breach waiting to happen, whatever the user sends can easily take over your web process.

Comment: I know, but I'll have a protection system against file manipulation and sql injections and other security breaches.

Comment: Also it is in a Virtual Environment.

Comment: Better duplicate: [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2220699/369450)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between eval, exec, and compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`eval` can only evaluate [Python *expressions*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html), not statements. A function definition is a statement, not an expression.

Use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) to execute Python statements.

See the [*Top-level components* document](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/toplevel_components.html), which differentiates (among others) between [*file input*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/toplevel_components.html#file-input) and [*expression input*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/toplevel_components.html#expression-input):

> ```
> file_input ::=  (NEWLINE | statement)*
> ```
>
> This syntax is used in the following situations:
>
> [...]
>
> - when parsing a string passed to the `exec` statement;

and

> [...] The string argument to `eval()` must have the following form:
>
> ```
> eval_input ::=  expression_list NEWLINE*
> ```

Do **NOT** use this to execute untrusted user-supplied text. `eval()` and `exec` are not guarded against malicious users, and they can and *will* take over the web process if you use this.

In fact, there is no 'safe' way to ever do this, other than running the code in a throw-away virtual machine with all services firmly bolted shut. Run a new virtual machine for new code, throw away the whole VM when done or after a timeout.

Comment: Can I still store the evaluation of the code with exec?

Comment: I'd like to add that what you're trying to do sounds a bit like bad design, unless you really know what you're doing. But who knows what John Galt is up to?

Comment: @JohnGalt: an expression has a value, a statement doesn't need to. For example, a function `def` doesn't have a value, it just defines the function (then there's a entry in the local namespace that has a value, namely a `Callable`, but that's another thing!)

Comment: @JohnGalt: That's the reason it's called `eval`: it can *evaluate* the value of expressions. Things that don't have values can't be `eval`ed, and, even if you could, wouldn't have a value.