# Python class written in string to literal object

Tags: python, string, class, object

I am trying to save a class written in string format to a database, then read this and load the class as literal class.

How can I do this?

```
test = """
class Test:
    def __init__(self, test_name):
        self.test_name = test_name
    
    def print_name(self):
        print(self.test_name)
"""

Test = eval(test)
test_obj = Test(test_name='test1')
```

It would be better together if I also know how to save the object instance in string format since I will save the instance to the database as well, like saving pickle.

Many thanks.

Comment: This doesn't appears to be a great idea to save code as strings… What's the use case for something like this? Why not pickle…?

Comment: Pickle needs class definition in order to load it. Without the class it will fail to load its data. I want to save the class anytime I want to, like a script in javascript, some of them will be deleted or marked from database so I will use them all in distinct ways..

Comment: @deceze For further explanation, I am developing many machine learning models, and models could be slightly different from each other so I want to save them and use the ones that have the best performance though...

Answer (score 1):

Almost a duplicate but I had to combine two answers.
If you have your class saved in a file - which you probably have - you are in luck:

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function) you want to use the `inspect.getsource`.

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698028/why-is-pythons-eval-rejecting-this-multiline-string-and-how-can-i-fix-it) you will then need to call the `exec` function on the string to retrieve the saved class.

Putting things together:

```
import inspect

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    def print(self):
        print(self.a)

text = inspect.getsource(Test)
exec(text)
```

As for retrieving a code of a class that is not saved in the file I didn't find a way and the first linked question's answer suggests that there isn't any.

Comment: this causes an error "TypeError: <module '__main__'> is a built-in class"

Comment: this exact `ctrl+c`'d code or your application of this code to your problem? I'm running python 3, this is in a separate source file and it is the only code being run. It works. So I can't reproduce the error. However it seems to me that you are calling the `getsource` on something built-in which is causing the error. As mentioned in the first answer, this only works for a code you have saved in a file.

Comment: I am running it on the jupyter notebook, but only source is the above, running in a single cell.

Comment: I'm not sure if a jupyter notebook qualifies as having the source saved in a file. I don't use them much. Could you please try running the code in a common .py file?