# How can I use Python's exec() and eval() to execute arbitrary code AND return a value afterwards?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a function that will let me execute code passed as a string, but also return a value upon completion. I have found Python's `exec` and `eval`, each of which manage to do a part of what I want:

- `exec` lets me execute some lines of code which I pass as a string: print to the console; set or change variables; write to files etc.
- `eval` lets me evaluate a single expression and returns the value of this expression.

However, the functionality I want is to combine these: with a single function call, I want to execute some arbitrary code, and then return a value, which might be dependent on the code executed.

To contextualise, I want to modify the in-built Pickle `__reduce__` method so that I can execute some code in the background while the object un-pickles. However, at the end of that code execution, I still want to return the original object that was pickled.

[Pickle's `__reduce__` has to return a function which is used to reassemble the object on un-pickling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__), so I want a use of `eval` and `exec` that lets me combine their usage into a single function call.

As an example, my code might look something like this:

```
def __reduce__(self):
    code = """with open("flag.txt", "w") as f:\n\tf.write("A flag I have left!")\ndict()"""

    return exec, (code, ), None, None, iter(self.items())
```

The odd return formatting is a quirk of Pickle. The oddly formatted code string should do this:

```
with open("flag.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("A flag I have left")
dict()  # I'm trying to get the intepreter to 'evaluate' this final line
```

However, this doesn't work, as `exec` just does nothing with this final line, and returns `None`. If I swap, and use `eval` instead, then I get an error too, as `eval` can't do anything with the lines above.

I ave tried using the in-built `compile` method, but this doesn't actually seem to help because `eval` still won't evaluate compiled execution code.

I also see that this problem has popped up elsewhere on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698028/why-is-pythons-eval-rejecting-this-multiline-string-and-how-can-i-fix-it) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74218830/how-can-i-handle-eval-exec-multiline-as-first-in-first-out?noredirect=1&lq=1)) but I'm unsatisfied with the answers provided, because they involve defining new functions, which are then useless in the context of getting Pickle to execute them on un-pickling, where the interpreter is naive of their definition.

Is there any way to neatly combine these expressions to achieve arbitrary execution as well as returning a value?

Comment: Okay, so what is your **question**? What happened when you tried using `exec` and `eval`? What is supposed to happen instead, and how is that different? What exactly do you need a "solution" for, and why is "the behaviour of Python's return when it is faced with an or statement." relevant to the problem? What actually is the difficulty you are encountering?

Comment: Or did you mean "how can I have the code automatically choose whether to use `exec` or `eval`, according to the input?" In this case - it isn't remotely clear how you intend for the system to work, or what **concrete problem you are trying to solve** (where is the input coming from? Why is it useful to use either `exec` or `eval` on that input at all?).

Answer (score -2):

The best solution I could find to this problem is one based on some code from [Yannic Kilcher](https://github.com/yk/patch-torch-save/blob/master/patch_torch_save.py).

You can combine the functions like this:

```
eval("exec(exec_code) or to_return")
```

`eval` will always try to return the value of the expression you have passed. If you pass a conditional expression, like the one above, then it will try and evaluate each part in turn to find the value of the whole conditional. As such, it will run your `exec` code, achieving what you need there, and then, finding that it evaluates to `None`, will return whatever the value of `to_return` is, because of the `or`. Therefore, if you make `to_return` your dictionary object constructor, then your code will run the `exec` statement first upon un-pickling, and then return a dictionary object as intended.