# Expression expected in ?: operator

Tags: c#, if-statement

why can't I have something like:

```
Some_Function ? myList.Add(a) : throw new Exception();
```

Why can't I throw exception in else part of ?: operator? what is the main purpose of ?: operator?

**Suggestion**
If anybody else wondered about the same thing, beside reading the answers below, i suggest that you read this post as well..
[Expression Versus Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement)

Comment: Because it's C#, not C++.

Comment: Because both sides need to return a value of the same type, you can do what you want with if/else.

Comment: `List.Add` is a void method, so `myList.Add(a)` is not an expression.

Comment: Because the ternary operator is not designed for that.

Comment: What do u mean? we have ?: operator in C# too.. which part of this is C++ specific?

Comment: @Dena Just because you have the same operator in c++ and c#, it doesn't mean it works the same way in both languages.

Comment: It's worth mentioning the error message: `Invalid expression term 'throw'`

Comment: @Dena, it is not correct to think of the conditional operator shorthand for if/else, as you have learned the 2 are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answers and comments are of course true (we can refer to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)), though my understanding of the question is more like, "why does it have to be that way?".

According to the [C# 5.0 specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029), the conditional operator forms an *expression*, not a *statement*.  I suspect that the reason why it's not a *statement*, thus preventing you from doing something like `a ? b() : throw e` is simply because we already have a statement construct for achieving basically the same thing; namely, `if..else`.

```
if (a) { b(); } else { throw e; }
```

The benefit of the **conditional operator** is that it can be used within statements or other expressions.

```
bool? nb = GetValue();
if (nb ?? (a ? b() : c())) { throw e; }
```

Comment: +1 for being the only person to make the quite important distinction that the conditional operator requires 2 expressions and not statements.

Comment: @BenRobinson He doesn't strictly say that, just that it *forms* an expression... (+1 for referencing the spec, though, that's the only real answer to "why doesn't C# do x?")

Comment: @Rawling, OK but close enough.

Comment: else, throw e. I can imagine the compiler chucking e through a window.

Comment: (╯°□°)╯︵ ǝ (@CalvinSmith suggestions for a unicode broken window welcome)

Answer (score 3):

Because it is defined as:

> ```
> null-coalescing-expression ? expression : expression
> ```

As you can read in [?: Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

> The conditional operator (?:) **returns** one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression.

One of both *expression* is evaluated depending on the boolean value of *null-coalescing-expression*.

Since neither of your two code fragments are [expressions that evaluate to a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement) (`List.Add()` is `void` and an exception doesn't evaluate to a value either), this can't compile.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remember that Ternary operator must return something and `List.Add` is a `void` method so it fails. Both the sides must be compatible and should return something.

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) says:

> The condition must evaluate to true or false. If condition is true,
>   **first_expression** is evaluated and becomes the result. If condition is
>   false, **second_expression** is evaluated and becomes the result.

And `myList.Add(a)` is not an expression.

Comment: More specifically both things it can return must be compatible types

Comment: @HenkHolterman no, implicit conversions will be applied, documenation mentions about that

Answer (score 1):

See ***[?: Operator on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ty67wk28.aspx)***. Its clearly explained there.

The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression. Following is the syntax for the conditional operator.

**condition ? first_expression : second_expression;**

The condition must evaluate to true or false. If condition is true, first_expression is evaluated and becomes the result. If condition is false, second_expression is evaluated and becomes the result. Only one of the two expressions is evaluated.
Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.
You can express calculations that might otherwise require an if-else construction more concisely by using the conditional operator. For example, the following code uses first an if statement and then a conditional operator to classify an integer as positive or negative.

The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression. Following is the syntax for the conditional operator.

The condition must evaluate to true or false. If condition is true, first_expression is evaluated and becomes the result. If condition is false, second_expression is evaluated and becomes the result. Only one of the two expressions is evaluated.
Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.
You can express calculations that might otherwise require an if-else construction more concisely by using the conditional operator. For example, the following code uses first an if statement and then a conditional operator to classify an integer as positive or negative.