# Purpose of #define foo() do { } while (0)

Tags: c, loops

While browsing sources of LinCAN driver, I found some macros that baffled me.

```
#else /*CONFIG_PREEMPT*/
#define can_preempt_disable()      do { } while (0)
#define can_preempt_enable()       do { } while (0)
#endif /*CONFIG_PREEMPT*/
```

I understand the usefulness of

```
do { 
  ...;
  if(condition) break;
  ... 
} while (0);
```

using `break` as a kind of `throw`. I semi-understand wrapping a sequence of functions like

```
#define FOO() do { foo(); bar(); } while (0)
```

to avoid caveats with braceless `if`. I understand sometimes "no-op statements" are required for a #define. But why this particular kind? specifically, empty braces, false condition, do...while? Some syntax caveats I can't quite grasp?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [complete passage from the relevant file](http://sourceforge.net/p/ortcan/lincan/ci/master/tree/lincan/include/can_sysdep.h#l251) is:

```
#if !defined(CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT) && ( defined(CONFIG_PREEMPT) ||
    (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,0)) )
#define can_preempt_disable preempt_disable
#define can_preempt_enable preempt_enable
#else /*CONFIG_PREEMPT*/
#define can_preempt_disable() do { } while (0)
#define can_preempt_enable() do { } while (0)
#endif /*CONFIG_PREEMPT*/
```

Thus, the first part is the code you get when you've asked for pre-emption protection, otherwise you get the empty, do-nothing, loops.

I guess they're written like that for the usual reasons, i.e. to ensure that the macro still is a valid statement.

There shouldn't be a terminating semicolon in the definition, since that will be in the code using these, such as [this function](http://sourceforge.net/p/ortcan/lincan/ci/master/tree/lincan/src/c_can.c#l839) which begins:

```
int c_can_wakeup_tx(struct canchip_t *chip, struct msgobj_t *obj)
{
    can_preempt_disable(); 

    ...
```

So, clearly the macro is used like any other function call, and the semicolon is right there where the macro is invoked. This is very normal.

**UPDATE 2**: Defining it to a `;` leads to double semicolons which is ugly, at least in my opinion. An <strike>empty brace pair `{}` would work</strike> I guess, but this `do/while` construct is even more idiomatic since it's often used in cases like these.

**UPDATE 3**: As pointed out in a comment, an empty brace pair won't work since then you can't put a semicolon after the call. Aah. Thanks!

Comment: That's not quite what I meant - not semicolon at the end, but instead of the whole construct, `#define can_preempt_disable() ;`. Semicolon is a valid null statement. `can_preempt_disable();`  would evaluate to `;;` harmlessly. Alternatively, plain empty block `{ }` if you're concerned about braceless `if...else`

Comment: @SE If you did `#define can_preempt_disable() ; ` then `if(foo()) can_preempt_disable(); else bar();` -> `if(foo());; else bar();` which is a syntax error. If you defined it to empty, `#define can_preempt_disable()` , then `while(foo()) can_preempt_disable();` -> `while(foo());` would produce a warning with at least some compilers (e.g. clang), and you'd be able to use can_preempt_disable() in places you shouldn't, e.g `for(;can_preempt_disable();)`

Comment: "An empty brace pair {} would work I guess" -- No, it wouldn't ... `if (x) can_preempt_disable(); else ...` won't compile. The important feature of `do { } while(0)` is that it isn't terminated.

Comment: @JimBalter Thanks, I knew it but somehow failed to remember when I wrote that. Edited.

Comment: A better idea however, is to embrace a coding style where you always use {} after every control statement. Then you don't need to resort to obscure macro tricks. If you have such a careful coding style, then an empty brace pair will work just fine. Because it will give a compiler error when the programmer is sloppy.

Comment: @Lundin: I completely agree.`if()` with statement in the next line without braces was a fire'able offense with my previous employer. And as I started working for my current employer, I inherited code littered with surprises like `if(debug) [newline] // printf("some debug message");`. Unfortunately often we're forced to work on a big project where the "always braces" practice is not known.

Comment: Macros should not be dependent on coding style to work. Anyway, it's irrelevant to the question or to this answer.

Answer (score 23):

It is a common syntax for notifying the compiler that macro should be treated as a *statement* instead of as an *expression* ([statements vs expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19224/411882)).

In this case compiler will alert you if you try to use `can_preempt_disable()` as an expression. This means that we forced compile-time check that `can_preempt_disable()` is used as a statement. Compile-time checks are very often desirable.

Comment: `(void)0` would have achieved the goal of preventing the expression's value being used.