# Explaining the difference between a statement and an expression in c++

Tags: c++, expression

I am trying to understand thoroughly the difference between a *statement* and an *expression*
But i am finding it confusing even after reading this answer 
[Expression Versus Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement)
look at the following:

```
std::cout << "Hello there? " ;
```

I could say that it is a statement as it is ending with a ***semi- colon*** BUT i could also say
It is an expression since i have an ***ostream*** , an ***output operator*** and a ***string literal***
and this expression yields a value which is the left hand operand.
Which one is correct?

Comment: `<<` is predefined operator for `cout`. Don't get it for example of statement and expression - it is more a demonstration for predefined operator in C++. Look `printf` function and normal expressions (with variables and constants).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expression Versus Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement)

Comment: @Poldie Sorry no, that's for c#

Comment: @i486 Calling it "predefined" is misleading. It's provided by the library, not by the language.

Comment: @Poldie I told you  read that answer>

Comment: Well then every call to a method that returns something is an expression, following your way of thinking...

Comment: @Poldie C# and C++ are different languages. Before you mark a C++ question as a duplicate of a C# one, it's presupposed that you are aware of the differences rather than having others fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which one is correct?

Both: it is an expression statement. C and C++ let you put an expression into a body of code, add a semicolon, and make it a statement.

Here are some more examples:

```
x++;       // post-increment produces a value which you could use
a = 5;     // Assignment produces a value
max(a, b); // Call of a non-void function is an expression
2 + x;     // This calculation has no side effects, but it is allowed
```

Note that this is true in the specific case of C and C++, but may not be true in case of other languages. For example, the last expression statement from the list above would be considered invalid in Java or C#.

Answer (score 11):

Let's see what the C++ grammar can tell us:

```
statement:
  labeled-statement
  attribute-specifier-seq_opt expression-statement
  attribute-specifier-seq_opt compount-statement
  attribute-specifier-seq_opt selection-statement
  attribute-specifier-seq_opt iteration-statement
  attribute-specifier-seq_opt jump-statement
  declaration-statement
  attribute-specifier-seq_opt try-block

expression-statement:
  expression_opt ';'
```

So it is a statement; in particular, an "expression statement", which consists of a (potentially empty) expression followed by a semi-colon. In other words,

```
std::cout << "Hello there? "
```

is an expression, while

```
std::cout << "Hello there? " ;
```

is a statement.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of expression is given in the C Standard (6.5 Expressions)

> 1 An expression is a sequence of operators and operands that specifies
>   computation of a value, or that designates an object or a function, or
>   that generates side effects, or that performs a combination thereof.
>   The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced
>   before the value computation of the result of the operator.

As for expression-statements then they are ended with a semicolon. Here is the definition of the expression statement in C++

```
expression-statement:
expression opt;
```

And

> An expression statement with the expression missing is called a null
>   statement.

Relative to the last quote I would like to point to a difference between C and C++. In C++ declarations are statements while in C declarations are not statements. So in C++ you may place a label before a declaration while in C you may not do so. So in C you have to place a null statement before a declaration. Compare

**C++**

```
Label:
int x;
```

**C**

```
Label: ;
int x;
```

Comment: The op has read the grammar and regurgitating it here is no help.  Convoluting with C also not helpful.