# Expressions vs Literals && Expressions vs Statements

Tags: java

What's the significant difference between Expressions vs Literals && Expressions vs Statements in Java? I'm aware that an expression represents a simple value or a set of operations that produces a value. However, literals can also be a simple value which makes it a little confusing to make difference between them. Could smb explain the differences? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any literal is an expression, but not every expression is a literal (e.g. `x+2` is an expression, where `x` is a variable, but not a literal. `123` is an integer literal, and also an expression (a very simple one). But I do not see the relation to statements in your question.

Comment: But what is the difference between statements and expressions ?@anol

Comment: Statements don't evaluate to values. `for` and `if/else` are statements, for example.

Comment: Some confusion may come from the fact that in some languages, some kinds of statements may return values (e.g. `i++` in C/Java).
Anyway, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement) explains the difference between statements and expressions, and there are several similar questions in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

A literal is a notation for representing a fixed value in source code. For example: `'a'`, `"a"`, `Object.class`, and `1` are all literals. Their value is known at compile-time, and they are expressions, since they evaluate to a single value.

Statements are complete units of execution. Most statements terminate with a semicolon. For example: `new Object();` is a statement, while `new Object()` is an expression that returns a reference to a newly created object. Examples of statements that don't terminate with a semicolon are blocks and control flow statements.

Comment: None of the examples you've given of statements that end with a  semicolon is a 'unit of execution' at all, as they aren't executed.

Comment: You are right. I edited the answer, but didn't elaborate further since the question posted in anol's comment has a quite comprehensive answer already.