# Are any languages strictly "statement-oriented"?

Tags: expression, programming-languages, statements

Are there modern languages which are require each line to be a statement? [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19224/4728212) FORTRAN did this, but do any languages since C? 
I've heard of [Expression-oriented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression-oriented_programming_language) languages, including all functional programming languages, but I can't even find a term for the opposite, a "statement-oriented" language, or one that would not allow an expression, e.g. `x + 3;` or a call to a value-returning function without an assignment?

Answer (score 1):

This is typical of low-level compiler intermediate languages, such as [Three-adress codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_address_code).