# Why can't I throw exceptions from an expression-bodied member?

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-6.0

Using expression-bodied members allows you to define the body of a method or property as a single expression without a return keyword (should it return something).

For example it turns these

```
int Method1()
{
    return 5;
}

void Method2()
{
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

into these

```
int Method1() => 5;

void Method2() => Console.WriteLine();
```

A difference comes into play when you throw an exception from the body:

```
void Method3()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

However, the following will not compile:

```
void Method3() => throw new Exception();
```

with the following messages:

```
Warning The member 'Program.Exception()' does not hide an inherited member. The new keyword is not required.  
Error   'Program.Exception()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial  
Error   ; expected  
Error   Invalid token 'throw' in class, struct, or interface member declaration  
Error   Method must have a return type
Error   Invalid expression term 'throw'
```

---

Why?

Comment: nice. however a method which only throws exception is Exception thrower! and no use since you can directly throw exception :)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: a common scenario where I would expect this is in not yet implemented methods which, evidently, throw a `NotImplementedException`

Answer (score 35):

This happens because the first two code snippets (`5` and `Console.WriteLine`) are expressions. More specifically these are respectively `NumericLiteralExpression` and `InvocationExpression`.

The latter one (`throw new Exception()`) is a statement -- in this case: `ThrowStatement`.

If you look at the Roslyn SDK you'll notice that a `MethodDeclarationSyntax` object has a property `ExpressionBody` of type `ArrowExpressionClauseSyntax` which in turn has a property of type `ExpressionSyntax`. This should make it obvious that only expressions are accepted in an expression-bodied member.

If you look at the last code sample, you'll notice that it consists of a `ThrowStatementSyntax` which has in turn an `ExpressionSyntax` property. In our case we're filling that with an `ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax` object.

---

### What's the difference between an expression and a statement?

- [Expression Versus Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement) [Stackoverflow]
- [Statements, Expressions, and Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173142.aspx) [MSDN]

### Why doesn't it accept statements as well?

I can only guess here but I would assume it's because that would open up way too many side-effects just to be able to throw an exception. I don't believe an expression and a statement have a common ancestor in the inheritance so there'd be a lot of code duplication. In the end I assume it boiled down to simply not worth being the hassle, even though it makes sense in a way.

When you write a simple expression as part of a method body that gets in fact wrapped under a `ExpressionStatementSyntax` -- yes, both combined! This allows it to be grouped together with other statements under the `Body` property of the method. Under the hood, they must be unrolling this and extracting the expression from it. This in turn can be used for the expression-bodied member because at this point you're left with just an expression and no longer a statement.

One important note here however is the fact that a return statement is.. a statement. More specifically a `ReturnStatementSyntax`. They must have handled this explicitly and applied compiler magic though that does beg the question: why not do the same for `ThrowStatementSyntax`?

Consider the following scenario: suddenly, `throw` statements are accepted as well. However since an expression-bodied member can only have expressions as its body (duh) that means you have to omit the `throw` keyword and instead are left with `new Exception()`. How are you going to distinguish between intending a `return` statement and a `throw` statement?

There would be no difference between the expression-bodied variation of these two methods:

```
public Exception MyMethod()
{
    return new Exception();
}

public Exception MyMethod()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Both a `throw` and a `return` statement are valid method-endings. However when you omit them there is nothing that distinguishes the two -- ergo: you would never know whether to return or to throw that newly created exception object.

### What should I take away from this?

An expression-bodied member is exactly as the name says it is: a member with only an expression in its body. This means that you have to be aware of what exactly constitutes an expression. Just because it's one "statement" doesn't make it an expression.

Comment: There have been talks on github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues about throw statements and such becoming expressions on C# 7. I don't recall a particular issue, though.

Comment: Would be nice to see the working snippet in this answer.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger there is no working snippet -- throwing an exception from an expression-bodied member is simply not supported

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: Indeed -- you have to put an *expression* in an *expression* bodied member. The syntax is just intended to be a shortcut. If you're outside that shortcut, then just use the regular syntax.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: I know, I just said it would be nice to see it.

Answer (score 17):

This feature is coming in C#7. From https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/

> It is easy to throw an exception in the middle of an expression: just call a method that does it for you! But in C# 7.0 we are directly allowing `throw` as an expression in certain places:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public Person(string name) => Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
    public string GetFirstName()
    {
        var parts = Name.Split(" ");
        return (parts.Length > 0) ? parts[0] : throw new InvalidOperationException("No name!");
    }
    public string GetLastName() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Updating this question to add links to newer info around how `throw` can now be used as an expression in expression-bodied members, ternary expressions and null-coalescing expressions, now that C# 7 is released:

[What's new in C# 7 - Throw expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#throw-expressions).

[New Features in C# 7.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/).

Comment: Problem is this doesn’t seem to work: `false || throw new Exception("what about my throw is an expression?")`

Comment: What behaviour do you expect from that snippet?

Comment: The same behavior as `(object)null ?? throw new ArgumentNullException()`

Comment: @binki The throw expression is [explicitly only permitted](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.0/throw-expression.md) in operands of the `?:` conditional operator, as a second operator of the null coalescing `??` operator and as an expression body in lambdas or methods.

Comment: I wish we could do this with the return statement. `var something = GetSomethingOrDefault() ?? return;`

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer about why but a workaround:

```
void Method3() => ThrowNotImplemented();

int Method4() => ThrowNotImplemented<int>();

private static void ThrowNotImplemented()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private static T ThrowNotImplemented<T>()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jeroen Vannevel explained, we can only use expressions for expression bodied members.
I would not recommend this, but you can always encapsulate your (complex) code in an expression by writing a lambda expression casting it to an appropriate type and Invoke it.

```
public void Method3() => ((Action)(() => { throw new Exception(); })).Invoke();
```

This way you can still throw an exception in one line in an expression bodied member!

Probably there are good reasons not to do this.
But I think that it is a design flaw that expression bodied members are restricted to expressions like this and can be worked around like in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Although its a old thread, but C# now supports throw expressions which were added in C# 7.

Previously,

```
var colorString = "green,red,blue".Split(',');
var colors = (colorString.Length > 0) ? colorString : null
if(colors == null){throw new Exception("There are no colors");}
```

No more. Now, as **Null coalescing operator:**

```
var firstName = name ?? throw new ArgumentException ();
```

As **Conditional Operator:**

It is also possible in the Conditional Operator as well.

```
var arrayFirstValue = (array.Length > 0)? array[1] : 
  throw new Expection("array contains no elements");
```

**Expression bodied member:**

```
public string GetPhoneNumber () => throw new NotImplementedException();
```