# Does "statement" in Python mean "command"?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm learning from [Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/).  They use the term "statement" a lot.  Is that like the term "command"? What does it mean?

Comment: Looking for `python statement` on Google leads you directly to the [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html). See also the following chapter, Compound Statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In computer programming a statement is the smallest standalone element of an imperative programming language that expresses some action to be carried out. It is an instruction written in a high-level language that commands the computer to perform a specified action. A program written in such a language is formed by a sequence of one or more statements. A statement may have internal components (e.g., expressions).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(computer_science)

Comment: So if I understood it right, statement are like commands, but when you are coding you are using the term statement because it doesn't doing a action in real time like a command ?

Comment: @Benny Very simplistically a statement is when you tell the program to do something like `a = 5` or `if (x > 3) { return (x) } else { return (3) }`. The if - else thing is a compound statement btw. But something like `a == 3` isn't a statement, it's an expression, cause it's evaluating to something, not doing something

Comment: Some good info written by Joel Spolsky (founder of SO) himself in the accepted answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement

Comment: Understood thank you, and if it's okay, I have one more question:             Does the term "command" have a meaning in Python ?