# Calling functions in C# ternary operator

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

Why is this code not valid? Pretty sure it's legit in C /C++

Pseudocode:

```
String s = Console.ReadLine();
int x = 0;
Int32.TryParse(s, out x) ? Console.WriteLine("Foo") :  Console.WriteLine("bar");
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean `Console.WriteLine` instead of `Console.writeline`.

Comment: It's pseudo code. I'm typing this out on mobile. The question is about the ternary operator, the code will compile fine as an if-else

Comment: @Hank sorry about that, I thought the question was simple enough that it could be answered without having to compile it. I don't recall posting any error messages though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ternary operator is used to return values and those values must be assigned.

If you want to invoke void methods in a ternary operator, you can use delegates like this:

```
String s = Console.ReadLine();
int x = 0;
(Int32.TryParse(s, out x) ? new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("Foo")) : () => Console.WriteLine("bar"))();
```

Answer (score 1):

console.writeline return void.. The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement), in C#, not every expression can be used as a statement.