# Reactive: Lambda compilation syntax error

Tags: c#, lambda, system.reactive

I've this code:

```
IObservable<bool> observable;
//Initialize observable...
observable
    .Do(availability => availability ? this.ConnectionAvailable() : this.ConnectionUnavailable(""))
    .Subscribe();
```

where,

```
private void ConnectionAvailable() {//...}
private void ConnectionUnavailable(string message) {//...}
```

I've getting this error at `<<1>>`:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Any ideas?

Comment: The first question is: why you've sent an empty string as parameter to `ConnectionUnavailable` while it doesn't accept any parameter based on declaration `this.ConnectionUnavailable("")`?

Comment: Well, the `?`-operator will return some value, whereby your method returns nothing.

Comment: How could a refactor this?

Comment: If you want to invoke void methods in a ternary operator, you can use delegates example https://stackoverflow.com/a/38451083/2946329

Comment: You are not forced to use ternary operator here - just use regular if else. `.Do(availability => { if (availability) { ... } else { ... }})`

Comment: @Jordi - Also there's no need for the `.Do`/`.Subscribe` combo - just use `.Subscribe`.