# C# if then else shorthand won't compile

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

The following compiles ok:

```
if (_logon.LogonToConnector())
{
    MessageBox.Show("Logon Success");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Logon Failed");
}
```

But for the more concise equivalent:

```
_logon.LogonToConnector() ? MessageBox.Show("Logon Success") : MessageBox.Show("Logon Failure");
```

The compiler gives the error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement    UniformTestClient

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The ternary operator is used to return values and those values must be assigned. Here is a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/38451083/2946329

Comment: _Where did I go wrong?..._ `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement UniformTestClient` Its all about that

Comment: Just a single google-search and you would have got the answer far faster then typing in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put it

```
MessageBox.Show(_logon.LogonToConnector() 
  ? "Logon Success"
  : "Logon Failed");
```

since ternary operator *must return* a value.

Comment: Too fast for me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operator returns a value based on true/false which has to be assigned. You can't shorten your if/else statement this way.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

You could do something like

```
string message = _logon.LogonToConnector() ? "Logon Success" : "Logon failed";

MessageBox.Show(message);
```