# Using In-Line Lambda functions as an argument

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am optionally display some content in the Unity Editor based on options chosen for a given component, this will be used when displaying a summary of options chosen on this current Component.

How I can make a function inline that returns a string, I want this function to be inline because there will be many of these and they will only useful in the line they are used in.

I have provided a code snippet that may clarify what I am trying to do.

I have used lambda functions like this in c++ and JavaScript, but not in c# and I've tried finding an answer on how to use them like this in C#.

```
var script = target as ButtonManager;//get reference to this Component 

EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Your current Interactive configuration", 
            "Parent: " + script.sceneParent.name + "\n",
            "Popup? " + ()=>{ if (script.isPopup) { return "Popup" } else { return "Change Scene"} }
            + "\n"
            );
```

**Edit:** *I can use a ternary operator to solve this problem*, but **I am curious as to how this would work with lambda functions**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a delegate inline in your string concatenation you need to create a new `Func<string>` from the anonymous method and execute it:

```
EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Your current Interactive configuration", 
            "Parent: " + script.sceneParent.name + "\n",
            "Popup? " + new Func<String>(()=>{ if (script.isPopup) { return "Popup"; } else { return "Change Scene";} })()
            + "\n"
            );
```

yuk.  You also need to consider things like variable closure. All that to say that the ternary operator is a cleaner solution here.

Comment: Thank you, although not practical here. Its very good to know if ever I run into a situation where this is clean and easy. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

What about the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator). Something like this:

```
return script.isPopup ? "Popup" : "Change Scene";
```

This could be also helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/38451083/2946329

Comment: Thank you, I thought about this but didn't know if it would work as an argument. Just tried it, cheers

Comment: @AidenFaulconer This could be also helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/38451083/2946329

Comment: Thats clever, never thought about instantiating a type Action inline... I'd post that as an answer, or edit your current one

Comment: One problem with the new Action(()=>) is that its void, how do you create an Action that has a return type?

Answer (score 1):

How about using ternary operator? instead of `()=>{ if (script.isPopup) { return "Popup" } else { return "Change Scene"} }` use `((script.isPopup) ? "Popup" : "Change Scene")`.
Also you can use delegates

Comment: Delegates are awesome, but it may not be as convenient as just defining a temporary function inline.