# Expected expression before 'if'

Tags: c, if-statement

Here is my code, the error code is

> Expected expression before 'if'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int friends = 2;

    printf("I have %d friend%s", friends, (if(friends != 1){"s"})
           );

    /*In english you say "friends" when you have 0 or more than one. However if you have 1 you say "friend" without the letter s. I have created a conditional code but there is an error in my print code*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't invent random C syntax :/

Comment: @DaveNewton You *can*.  It just won't compile.

Comment: @AndrewHenle And sometimes it _will_ becouse its _C_.

Comment: And even *if* the code worked it'd provoke the infamouse Undefined Behaviour foir the case of `friends` being equal to `1`, by missing to pass any string although one is expected by the format string.

Comment: time for a "*do what i MEAN!*" language ... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` is a *statement*, not an *expression*. Since a statement cannot be used inside of an expression, the `if` statement cannot be used either inside of an expression.

However, you can use the *ternary operator* instead, which is an expression, in order to create a conditional expression:

```
printf("I have %d friend%s", friends, friends != 1 ? "s" : "");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm a beginner and trying to learn the programming language C on my own. What exactly considers something an expression? Is 'if' conditional statements an expression too? Is that why I can't put it inside printf statement?

Comment: @sangminpark You have to distinguish between the terms *statement* and *expression*. `if` is an statement and `?:` is and expression. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement

Answer (score 2):

Specific to gcc, statement expressions are allowed. Please refer following:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html

Other problem with your code is that if statement does not have a rvalue. So the last statement of the statement expression should be a rvalue. Following code will work fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int friends = 2;

    printf("I have %d friend%s", friends, (char *)({char *ret = ""; if(friends != 1) ret="s";ret;})
           );

    /*In english you say "friends" when you have 0 or more than one. However if you have 1 you say "friend" without the letter s. I have created a conditional code but there is an error in my print code*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: True. let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `if` inside expression, but you can use [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) for that purposes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int friends = 2;

    printf("I have %d friend%s", friends, friends != 1 ? "s" : "");

    /*In english you say "friends" when you have 0 or more than one. However if you have 1 you say "friend" without the letter s. I have created a conditional code but there is an error in my print code*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm a beginner and trying to learn the programming language C on my own. What exactly considers something an expression? Is 'if' conditional statements an expression too? Is that why I can't put it inside printf statement?

Comment: I would recommend you to read some good C language book. Operators are used with operands to build expressions. For example the following is an expression containing two operands and one oprator 4 + 5. Becouse you cannot use statement in expression. Ternary operator is not statement so there is not problem with using it in expression. Hope you understand now @sangminpark.

Answer (score 1):

Being that the previous answers suggest the use of the ternary operator, perhaps the following equivalent output with different syntax might help also.

```
#include <studio.h>
int main(){
     int friends = 2;
     if(friends > 1){
          printf("I have %d friend%s",friends,"s");
     }else{
          printf("I have %d friend",friends);
    }
    return 0;
}
```