# Is it possible to insert an if condition inside a return statement in C?

Tags: c, coding-style

My purpose is trying to write a function as concise and short as possible.

```
int func(void)
{
    int a;
    return (
        a = 42,
        a++,
        if (a > 42) a *= -1,
        a);
}
```

I was expecting to return a -43. Instead I've got a compilation error.

Comment: How about just `return a;` after everything?

Comment: Concise and short would be `return -43;`

Comment: Have a look at the `?:` operator. You can't have an `if` inside the return statement.

Comment: What you have inside `return( ... )` is a comma operator. Expressions such as `a = 42` and `a++` are valid expressions that can be used with a comma operator; but `if (a>42) ... ` is a *statement*, and cannot be used in this way.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), which is a gcc extension to standard C, but [is also supported by many other compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6440021/12149471).

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My purpose is trying to write a function as concise and short as
> possible.

```
int a;

return (
   a = 42,
   a++,
   if (a > 42) a *= -1,
   a);
```

Can simply be rewritten as:

```
return -43;
```

Or if that's too short for your liking, then you're looking for the conditional operator (colloquially referred to as the ternary operator), which has the form:

```
/* if a is logically true (does not evaluate to zero) 
*  then evaluate expression b, otherwise 
*  evaluate expression c
*/
a ? b : c;
```

So the `return` statement can be rewritten as:

```
a = 42;
return ++a > 42 ? -a : a;
```

---

As of your objective, then there's no merit to it. You should not write clever code. It harms readability and maintainability. (Although in this case, it doesn't)

Remember:

1. *Simplicity is the
   ultimate sophistication.*
   — ***Leonardo da Vinci***
2. *Any fool can write code
   that a computer can
   understand. Good
   programmers write code
   that humans can
   understand.* ― ***Martin
   Fowler***
3. *Everything should be made
   as simple as possible —
   but no simpler.* —  ***Albert
   Einstein*** (attributed).¹

---

[1] — credit: @SteveSummit

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is writing the function don't write it in the main function. write it outside the main and call the function in main
The cause of your error is  because of your statement expression there is an explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45653540/14308832
So I guess you want to take `a` as parameter otherwise you can assign `a` as 42 in  `func`

```
int func(int a){
    a++;
    return (a > 42 ? a *= -1 : a);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d",func(42));
}
```

Comment: the main function is just for demonstration purposes, my point was about what can it be done inside a return statement. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
int main(void)
{
    int a;

    return (a = 42, a++, a > 42 ? a = a * -1 : a);
}
```

Comment: You *can* do this, but if you don't like being shunned by your co-workers for writing unmaintainable code, you should not do this.

Comment: Wait, why does your code outputs 213?

Comment: @viodid: main() has to return an integer between 0 and 255, so -43 is not going to work. But it's not a coincidence that 213+43=256. Read up on 2's complement.