# Is the return statement considered to be an expression statement in C?

Tags: c, expression

I heard that if an expression is followed by a semicolon, then it is considered to be an expression statement.

Source:
http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/329/lectures/node11.html

```
int x = 7;
x = 8;
x++;
x—-;
x = x << 1;
```

These are all expression statements.

But is this an expression statement too?

```
return 5;
```

And if not, then please throughly explain why.

And I would also appreciate it if you could tell whether the return satetement can be considered an expression statement in other languages as well.

Comment: No, and what difference does it make?

Comment: @500-internalservererror Because if it is not an expression statement then the above definition for it is false and I failed to get the idea of what really makes an expression statement, which I would like to know.

Comment: Every herring is a fish, but not every fish is a herring. Every expression statement is an expression followed by a semicolon, but not every expression followed by a semicolon is an expression statement.

Comment: @n.m.: Not every expression statement is an expression followed by a semicolon. An expression statement does not need to have an expression.

Comment: Which definition is wrong? Or which part of it? The linked page does not mention `return` at all.

Comment: @Gerhardh the linked page only says that an expression followed by a semicolon is an expression statement, and does not mention the return statement. But a return statement also includes an expression terminated by a semicolon hence my confusion, but turns out the definition only holds true if the statement is comprised by nothing but an expression and a semicolon. In fact, the definition is true, but still made me confused anyway.

Comment: It says: An expression statement has an expression and a semicolon. It does not say anything in the opposite direction. A => B does not imply B => A.

Comment: @Gerhardh yes, the root of the problem is merely my misinterpretation of the given definition and overlooking. It says it consists of an expression and a semicolon, but did not get that it was meant in a strict sense and that it does not allow an expression statement to have more because I read “consists of” but interpreted it as “have”. If something has something it does not mean it can not have something else as well. It was for me like: “If a line of code has an expression terminated by a semicolon then the line of code is an expression statement”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `return` statement and an expression statement are two different things.

Section 6.8.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) gives the syntax for an expression statement:

> expression-statement:
>
> - expression<sub>opt</sub>`;`

While section 6.8.6 gives the syntax of a `return` statement:

> jump-statement:
>
> - `goto` identifier`;`
> - `continue;`
> - `break;`
> - `return` expression<sub>opt</sub>`;`

Also, this is not an expression statement (in fact not a statement at all):

```
int x = 7;
```

But a **declaration**.

Comment: x = 8; is an expression statement because the expression before the semicolon is said to be an assignment expression, am I right?

Comment: @PatrikNusszer That is correct.  An assignment is a type of expression.

Answer (score 5):

This is basically answered by [Expression Versus Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19132/364696). The key question is: Does a `return` evaluate to a value (e.g. could you do `x = return 5;`?). Clearly it does not, so it is a statement, not an expression. Expression statements are just expressions used as statements; if it's not an expression, it can't be an expression statement, so `return` does not form an expression statement.

Answer (score 3):

No. [Expression statements](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.3p1) are (optional) expressions followed by `;`.

`return 5` isn't an expression. That's because it doesn't evaluate to a value (you can't assign `return 5` to anything) and because it's specifically defined as a [jump statement](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.6), which is a type of [statement](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8p1) distinct from [expression statements](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.3p1).