# What's the difference between an instruction and a function?

Tags: python-3.x

I have just started learning Python. I came across `del` instruction. I could not understand difference between an **instruction** and a **function** like `len()`.  I googled it but could not find the answer. Apologies if this question sounds childish.

Comment: Before asking for the difference, could you explain your understanding of what a function is?

Comment: "Instruction" isn't a defined term in the Python language documentation; `del ...` is a statement.

Comment: Related: [Expression Versus Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement)

Comment: @MadPhysicist A function is a piece of code that is called by name. It is not associated with any object like a method. It can be passed data to operate on. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am learning from https://pythoninstitute.org/free-python-courses/   del is written as instruction.

Comment: @tusharkhoche Then I would be wary of using that as a learning resource. There is a [`del` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement), so named because it is recognized by the use of the `del` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like `del`, `def`, `class`, `lambda`, `with`, `for`, `while`, etc. are all similar in that they are essentially special cases. They all have specifically-defined behavior, but that behavior is hardcoded into the python interpreter.

In the case of `def`, that behavior is to parse the following text in a certain way - as a function. Similar for `lambda`, as a lambda function, and for `class`, as a class.

In the case of `with`, the behavior is to take an argument, call `.__enter__()` on it, and assign the result to a name that's given after the `as` keyword. With `for`, it's the opposite - define the name before the `in` keyword, and then call `.__iter__()` on whatever's after, assigning each item in turn to the name.

`del` is similar, in that it has a built-in function - it removes the object from the current namespace. That's just what it does, hardcoded behavior of the interpreter. There are a couple of special cases baked in for iterable objects, in which case (IIRC) the compiler calls `.__delitem__()` on it.

---

Functions are a specific type of object with a specific programmer-defined behavior. They're defined with the `def` instruction.