# why errors arise at the first return and (:) operator?

Tags: c#, if-statement, recursion

```
public int factorial(int number)
        {
            number <= 0 ? return 1 : return number * factorial(number - 1);
        }
```

The compiler tells me to that the first **return** is an invalid expression and there is a **;** and **}** expected what should I do?

Comment: Typo, move both `return` keywords before `number` (so there's only one `return` keyword).

Comment: Thank you so much, the errors are gone but should I keep the `1` after the condition or there is a better code I can replace it with in case the condition is true?

Comment: `return` is a "statement". The ternary operator `? :` is an "expression". An expression can have a value, and can contain other expressions. But a statement must stand alone. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132/expression-versus-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the ternary operator incorrectly. You can't use `return`.

You actually want this:

```
return number <= 0 ? 1 : number * factorial(number - 1);
```

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

> `condition ? consequent : alternative`
>
> The condition expression must evaluate to true or false. If condition evaluates to true, **the consequent expression is evaluated, and its result becomes the result of the operation**. If condition evaluates to false, the alternative expression is evaluated, and its result becomes the result of the operation. Only consequent or alternative is evaluated.

This means that `consequent` and `alternative` should both evaluate to values that can be returned.